# How can q=mcp(deltaT) be made dimensionless?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, dimensional-analysis

Specifically, how can I make $m C_p$ dimensionless? I've tried using the Reynolds number and Peclet number definitions to plug into there but the closest I've gotten to was:

$q=\pi D Re Pe \frac{k}{4L}$

The problem is that k is not dimensionless and I can't find any way to take it out.
Any advice?

Comment: what are you trying to get at? are you trying to study the effects of $k$ or $l$. If so divide the equation by the length and conductivity scale in the problem. Or are you looking at the $\alpha$ parameter that arises in temperature diffusion equation

Comment: I'm trying to study how a change in Peclet number changes the heat flow. So I don't have a k and l value to give it. Only a Peclet number and change in Tmean

Comment: Are you sure this equation is correct? I assume $D$ is diameter and $L$ is some length scale. If that is the case, the right hand side of the equation has units of $k$ which is $q/\nabla T$ (heat over the gradient of temperature). This is dimensionally inconsistent with the left hand side which has just dimensions of $q$. I strongly suspect that you are missing some gradient of temperature in the problem